# Combining Grep and Paste command in bash

Tags: bash, grep, paste

very sorry to ask a stupid question but I'm getting crazy with this thing.

So, I'm in bash and I have some files:

```
ls
a.bed
b.bed
c.bed
```

all I want to do is create a variable that have all the 3 of them separated with a comma, this is the output I search for:

```
a.bed, b.bed, c.bed
```

What I'm using for now (but have spaces instead of commas is):

```
beds=$(ls|grep .bed)
```

which have

```
a.bed b.bed c.bed
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Do you want `a.bed, b.bed, c.bed`, or would `a.bed,b.bed,c.bed` suffice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with ls 'x' and 'm' options alone:

```
beds=$(ls -xm *.bed)
```

> echo $beds
>   a.bed, b.bed, c.bed

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the downvote. x is not needed , it seems to me it's the defaut.

Comment: Just don't put quotes around the variable if you don't want the possibility of embedded line breaks.

Answer (score 7):

I would use `printf` and its `-v` option, followed by a use of parameter expansion.

```
$ printf -v beds '%s, ' *.bed
$ beds=${beds%, }
```

The first line produces `a.bed, b.bed, c.bed,` . The second line trims the trailing `,` .

If you only need a single-character separator, an alternative is to use an array with `IFS`:

```
$ beds=$(a=(*.bed); IFS=,; echo "${a[*]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that is a bit wacky:

```
beds=$( tr \  , <<< $(ls *.bed))
```

In the example above, we get rid of the newlines in the `ls` output simply by executing it with `$()`.  Then we use the resulting string as input to `tr` which replaces all spaces with commas.

My favorite is using the built in -xm parameters in ls, but this particular answer can apply to other executables that do not provide the rich set of output formats that `ls` does.

Comment: I suppose that I have to comment that spaces in the filenames will give you incorrect response.

Answer (score 0):

Overkill for this specific case but just as an FYI you could do:

```
$ bedsArr=( *.bed )
$ bedsStr=$( printf '%s, ' "${bedsArr[@]:0:$((${#bedsArr[@]} - 1))}"; printf "%s\n" "${bedsArr[@]: -1:1}" )
$ printf '%s\n' "$bedsStr"
a.bed, b.bed, c.bed
```